# How do I include has_many relationships in a Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models, `Artist` and `User` that are connected through a third model, `ArtistMembership`.

From the edit/new Artist form, I want to be able to edit the role of any User in an existing ArtistMembership relationship for that Artist, delete ArtistMemberships, and add new AtistMembership relationships, which would include a User and :role.

Here's my Artist model:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :artist_memberships, foreign_key: "artist_id", dependent: :destroy

attr_accessible :bio, :created_at, :email, :location, :name, :updated_at, :website, :pic
accepts_nested_attributes_for :artist_memberships, :allow_destroy => :true
...
end
```

Here's my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
has_many :artist_memberships, foreign_key: "user_id"
...
end
```

Here's my ArtistMembership model:

```
class ArtistMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :artist, class_name: "Artist"
    belongs_to :user, class_name: "User"

  attr_accessible :artist_id, :created_at, :role, :user_id
end
```

If I have a _form.hml.erb too, for editing Artists that starts:

```
<%= form_for @artist do |artist_form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= artist_form.label :name %>
    <%= artist_form.text_field :name %>
  </div>
..
  <div class="actions">
    <%= artist_form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

how can I create the related ArtistMembership forms for the aforementioned functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is helpful for you, see this [field_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)

you can use [accepts_nested_attributes_for(*attr_names)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed.  I think I was complicating the problem too much.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this method.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Refer to the "One-to-many" section.

But if I were you, I would rather use the "Nested Resource" technic.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources